VS Code light themes making symbols invisible
VS Code 1.94.2 on macOS Sequoia 15.0.1
I usually don't mess around with themes much other than trying out different coding fonts. I've been using dark themes for months but just felt like using a light theme. I found that with all the light themes the colour for many symbols, punctuation, operators is the same as the background colour, or close enough that I can't see them:
Light (Visual Studio) Visual Studio Light:

Solarized Light:

With text selected they're not as bad:


Dark themes are fine:


As I say I don't usually mess with the theme so I don't think I've manually changed the colour settings. Nobody else uses my laptop. The only theme-related extension I have installed is Peacock so I tried disabling it but that made no difference.
I've looked through the settings to no avail and Googling doesn't seem to bring up other people with this problem.
This is what I see if I use "Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes": 

do you see the operators if you switch of font ligatures? Use TextMate Scope Inspector to see why they are white

@rioV8 Turning ligatures off didn't make a difference. Using TextMate Scope Inspector (if I'm doing it right) I can see that they are white but I can't see why. I'll add an image.

do you have a setting for Theme customization for keyword.operator that colors these scopes bold-white-italic, and not have the customization be a dark theme name specific one, why would you draw an operator italic

Either I don't have such a thing or I don't know where to look for it. Would it be in settings.json?

look in all your settings.json, global and workspace, use command palette and search for json

Yes! In the defaultSettings.json I found this: { "scope": "keyword.operator", "settings": { "foreground": "#FFFFFF", "fontStyle": "italic bold" } } and I have absolutely no idea where it came from. Ths VS Code timeline for the file is empty. It also has these other three rules - should I delete those as well? "scope": "comment.line", "settings": { "fontStyle": "italic" } and "scope": "entity.name.section", "settings": { "fontStyle": "bold" } and "scope": "storage.type", "settings": { "fontStyle": "bold" } But: "Editor is read-only because the file system of the file is read-only"?

Can't find them anywhere else and can't find a way to edit them. This is much more unintuitive that VS Code usually is.

If I disable all extensions that fixes it. But if I reenable them all and then disable them all one by one that does not fix it! How can I find which extension is the culprit?

I have an almost clean install of VSC 1.94.2, and I do not have any "scope" in the default settings json  file. disable all extension, inspect defaultSettings.json, enable extensions one by one, maybe restart VSC each time, and inspect defaultSettings.json, start with the extensions that might do something with theme or workspace, an extension should not modify the defaultSettings.json only the global and workspace/folder settings files

Thanks. Enabling one by worked where disabling one by one failed for some reason. The culprit turned out to be m68k-mot-syntax

send the developer an issue that changing a theme color IS NOT done by a language/grammar extension

looking at the source code, you can modify the package.json of the extension because there will be no new update (2 years ago last update)

@rioV8 The project has already been archived. I think I installed three m68k asm syntax extensions at the same time once because they were all incomplete and then didn't uninstall any of them. So I just deleted this one and kept the others. I just accepted an answer thinking it was yours but it was somebody else. If you submit an answer I'll accept yours instead. Thanks for your help either way!

The problem extension was found by enabling the extensions 1 by 1.
It was altehex.m68k-mot-syntax.
The package.json file of the extension contains a section:
      "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope": "comment.line",
            "settings": {
              "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
          },
          {
            "scope": "keyword.operator",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#FFFFFF",
              "fontStyle": "italic bold"
            }
          }
        ]
      }

and a few other scopes.
The line "foreground": "#FFFFFF" forces all keyword.operator scopes to be white in all themes. It should be removed.
Also the forcing of all comment.line to be italic is wrong, the theme controls that, and also should be removed.

If this extension is still useful for you do the following:

in the extension folder create a folder with the name: my-m68k-mot-syntax
copy all files from the extension repo (using a zip file) to the my-m68k-mot-syntax folder
edit package.json:

change the version number to: "version": "1.1.0"
remove the scope keyword.operator
remove the scope comment.line
Or remove all of editor.tokenColorCustomizations, you can do this in settings.json for each theme separate


no need for a 2048x2048 icon file (170kb), scale the png image to 256x256

You can use the TextMate Scope Inspector to find the scope names you want to give a different color in your settings.json. It is the Theme that determines the color not the language syntax.

The problem was found by essentially doing an extension bisect to by caused by altehex.m68k-mot-syntax. I suppose if you really needed it, you could at least only enable it for workspaces where you need it.
